# sort part of the name

Tags: filenames

I have multiple names that have the same prefix but the prefix is unknown.

I want to sort only by the digits in the name.

i.e

```
abcd_006-123
abcd_006-232
bbcd_w_006-112
```

so `bbcd_w_006-112` should be the first

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could define a glob sorting function like:

```
digitsOnly() REPLY=${REPLY//[^0-9]} # removes all non-digits
```

and then use it as:

```
print -rC1 -- *(no+digitsOnly)
```

There, the `n` glob qualifier turns the `numericglobsort` option for that one glob extension, and `o+function` sorts based on the output (via `$REPLY`) of the `function`.

`print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `c`olumn.

Remember that if you use `ls`, `ls` does sort the list of files before printing (alphabetically by default). With the GNU implementation of `ls`, that sorting can be avoided with the `-U` option:

```
ls -ldU -- *(no+digitsOnly)
```

You can do something similar with `perl` with:

```
perl -le 'sub digitsOnly {$_=shift; s/\D//gr};
          print for sort {digitsOnly($a) <=> digitsOnly($b)} <*>'
```

Or to run a command on that list of files:

```
perl -l0e 'sub digitsOnly {$_=shift; s/\D//gr};
           print for sort {digitsOnly($a) <=> digitsOnly($b)} <*>' |
   xargs -r0 ls -ldU --
```